# Calculate Elapsed time in python in specific format

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program to determine the time and date corresponding to a elapsed number of seconds since 00: 00: 00 on 1 January 2016.

But i wanted my result in specific format.
i.e should be the corresponding hour (in military time), minute, second, day of the month, month name, year, and day of the week name (Sunday – Saturday). 
for example,output should look like the following

```
23:59:32 2 January 2018 Tuesday
```

i tried to code this

```
import time
start = time.time()
#do something
end = time.time()
temp = end-start
print(temp)
hours = temp//3600
temp = temp - 3600*hours
minutes = temp//60
seconds = temp - 60*minutes
print('%d:%d:%d' %(hours,minutes,seconds))
```

But i could only get the hours, minutes and seconds part,
Is there any way i can get the month,year,and week name too ?

Also i'm trying to handle leap years too.since a leap year has 366 days with 29 days in February. Leap years are years that are evenly divisible by 4, with the exception of those evenly divisible by 100 but not 400.

Comment: Use `time.strftime()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: @SRingne the elapsed time will be in seconds. How do you expect to get a date like `23:59:32 2 January 2018 Tuesday` from a seconds (float) value?

Answer (score 0):

To format a datetime you can use strftime().

```
import datetime
my_time = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=1, day=2, hour=23, minute=59,second=32)
print (my_time.strftime("%X %-d %B %Y %A"))
```

If you want to change the format use [this table for reference](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: sir i have to calculate the elapsed time

Comment: @EfronLicht's solution works from what I understand you need; just change `year = 2001` to `year = 2016 ` in @EfronLicht's function.  So, if you want 1302330 seconds since 1/1/2016 use: `my_time = convert_seconds_since_jan_1(1302330)` then use `print(my_time.strftime("%X %-d %B %Y %A"))`.  You will get "01:45:30 16 January 2016 Saturday"!

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the [Datetime Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). Handling dates and times is trickier than it appears! That's why it's good that Python has datetime handling built-in. Datetime and timedelta objects account for leap years and leap seconds, and they handle operations like addition and subtraction 'intuitively'.

```
import datetime
def convert_seconds_since_jan_1(seconds):
    JAN_1_2001 = datetime.datetime(year = 2001, month = 1, day = 1)
    added_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds = seconds)    
    return (JAN_1_2001+added_time)
```

Getting the weekday is simply a matter of string formatting. Remember that weekdays are modulo 7!

Comment: Sir its not giving me right result.
i ran your function ` import time` `convert_seconds_since_jan_1(time.time())`
and got result as `datetime.datetime(2048, 3, 28, 21, 45, 37, 857000)`

Comment: wanted result in format like this `23:59:32 2 January 2018 Tuesday `

Comment: this is taking an input where x is the seconds since january 1 2001.

If you want today, use datetime.datetime.today(). 
If you want the distance from january first, use (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.datetime(year = 2001, month = 1, day = 1)).total_seconds()

Comment: i want time elapsed since 1 January 2016 and current date time., with the month name, and week,if you could edit ur answer accordingly sir

Comment: for running this function `convert_seconds_since_jan_1` what argument to pass